# How to launch i7z_GUI (segmentation fault)?

Tags: debian, monitoring, cpu

I tried many ways to launch an application `i7z_GUI` on Debian, but it just won't start.

I tried it both as `root` as shown below and as a user:

```
su-to-root -X -c /usr/sbin/i7z_GUI
gksu -u root /usr/sbin/i7z_GUI
./usr/sbin/i7z_GUI
```

---

After properly setting up `sudo`, it wouldn't work either:

> Segmentation fault

it says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by **compiling** the application from its source code.

Answer (score 0):

It's a binary in /usr/sbin - if `/usr/sbin/` is in your $PATH, you can run it like so:

```
i7z_GUI
```

Otherwise, run it by prefixing the full path:

```
/usr/sbin/i7z_GUI
```

There is no man page for i7z_GUI, but the man page for `i7z` says:

> i7z needs to be run in super user (root) mode.

If you are trying to run either of these as a non-root user then you need to use sudo, for example:

```
sudo i7z_GUI
```

or

```
sudo /usr/sbin/i7z_GUI
```

depending on whether `/usr/sbin` is in your $PATH or not.